# Extend MapField for use with Custom Map webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, blackberry, java-me, maps

I want to be able to use the mapfield in the same manner as Blackberry maps.

But with the Maps being obtained from my own webservice.

There must be a way of extending the field and overriding some getMap method, but I can't see to find any such method.

Help would be appreciated as BB Docs aren't that great.

**Edit:**  Ive found this:
[http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/maps/ui/MapField.html#displayMapURL(java.lang.String)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/maps/ui/MapField.html#displayMapURL%28java.lang.String%29)

Not sure what to make of it

**Edit2:**
It seems to require a blackberry URL that is basically a stored URL of a current map state so it can be easily called up again via this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that [MapField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/MapField.html) is not intended to be extensible in the manner that you have described.  My guess is that even if you could somehow "replace" the map data backing the Field, you would end up having to override pretty much every other method as well in order to work properly with your data.  You might be better off just building your own component.

Comment: Hey, I clicked the link and realise I too have been looking at an older version? Released in 6.0 is a more advanced one. And Specfically I found this but not sure what to make of it. See my Q edit.